# Exception: Given path format is not supported when the user input C:\Name

Tags: c#, console

I made a small console app to help users copy all content from one directory to another. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace CopyEdriveContentToLocalFolder
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
        {
            DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
            DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

            CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
        }
        public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

            // Copy each file into the new directory.

            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
            }


            // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.

            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
            {

                DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                    target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
                CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Specify a name for your Parent folder.
            string ParentFolderName;
            string ChildFolderName;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome!!\n\nThis program will help you copy all content of your CD/DVD to a new directry \n\n" +
                "naming convention must be in this format: ### #####\n\nPress Enter to start...\n");

            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)

            {
                Console.Write("Enter Parent folder Name: ");
                ParentFolderName = Console.ReadLine();
                string text = ParentFolderName;
                string contains = " ";
                bool b = text.Contains(contains);
                if ( b == true)
                {

                    //Set the Child folder name to be same as Parent.
                    ChildFolderName = ParentFolderName;
                    string TopLevel = @"" + ParentFolderName;
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(TopLevel))
                    {
                        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(TopLevel, ChildFolderName);
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The Folder: \"{0}\" already exists.\n\n", TopLevel);
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Exit the program and re-name the folder .\n\n");
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Press Enter twice to exit.");
                        System.Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                    }
                    // To create a string that specifies the path to a subfolder under your 
                    // top-level folder, add a name for the subfolder to folderName.
                    //string pathString2 = @"c:\"+ ParentFolderName +"\\" + ChildFolderName;
                    // You can extend the depth of your path if you want to.
                    //pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, "SubSubFolder");

                    string sourceDirectory = @"E:\";
                    string targetDirectory = TopLevel +"\\" + ChildFolderName;

                    Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);
                    string root = TopLevel + "\\" + ChildFolderName + "\\System Volume Information";
                    //This part will delete the System generated folder.
                    // If directory does not exist, don't even try 
                    if (Directory.Exists(root))
                    {
                        foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(root))
                        {
                            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(files);
                            fileInfo.Delete(); //delete the files first. 
                        }

                        Directory.Delete(root);
                    }
                    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
                    System.Console.Write("All Neccery folders have been copied..\n\n" + "Pleace check the target directory.\n\n" +
                        "Hit Escape twice to exit or Enter to continue.\n");
                    // System.Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("The Folder: \"{0}\" already exists.\n\n", TopLevel);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAn Error has occurred due to NOT following the naming convention.\n\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Make sure the Folder name correct\n\nExit the program and restart.\n\n");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Press Enter twice to exit.");
                    System.Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }

            }

        }
    }
    }
```

The Exception I get of wrong format on this line:

```
 DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
```

if I have the drive hard coded Like @"C:\" it works fine..

```
string targetDirectory = @"c:\" + ParentFolderName + "\\" + ChildFolderName;
```

can some one help me please. I need to set the target directory and the source to be completely up to the user.
Thank you

Comment: If you're getting an exception you need to [tell us what the exception is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). And [use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to find out what `targetDirectory` is.

Comment: @DourHighArch Exception is in the title and target directory is user input as the question and code comments states. sorry long code but hopefully others would make a use of it one day.

Comment: Please read the link I posted; your title only contains a few words from the exception and not enough for us to tell what the problem is. My guess is the user doesn't have access to a folder or directory, or chose an invalid name. In general it's a bad idea to let a file path be “completely up to the user” because the rules for file paths are [highly non-intuitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247).

Comment: I agree at first The Drive was hard coded but my lead wants it to be up to the users to set the from and to. I figured out the issue I will Post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that "\" is used as an escape character inside strings. When users input D:\ C# doesn't treat it as a path. Therefor, `DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);` Throws exception of unrecognized path becuse `string targetDirectory` has incorrect path value. To solve the issue we do this:

```
Console.Write("Enter Parent folder Name: ");
path = @"" + Console.ReadLine();
```

This way users can input any directory. Ex) D:\test
In my code it creates a parent and child directory by saying `ChildFolderName = ParentFolderName;` The issue now is I can't have a path of D:\testD:\test 
To solve this you create another variable that store user input - first 3 char and assign it to childFolderName.

```
 path = @"" + Console.ReadLine();
 ParentFolderName = path.Substring(3); 
 ChildFolderName = ParentFolderName;
```

And:

```
string sourceDirectory = @"E:\";
string targetDirectory = path + "\\" + ChildFolderName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string targetDirectory = @"c:\" + ParentFolderName + "\" + ChildFolderName;
```

or this:

```
string targetDirectory = "c:\\" + ParentFolderName + "\\" + ChildFolderName;
```

Comment: `string targetDirectory = Path.Combine("c:\", ParentFolderName, ChildFolderName);`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the response I know I can get it to work this way as mentioned in the question. My issue is I want the user to be able to input the C:\ or D:\ I don't want it hard coded. I found this as a solution :  Console.Write("Enter Parent folder Name: ");
                ParentFolderName = @""+Console.ReadLine(); put this mean I can't have the Parent value and child Value the same as what I am doing now if you refer to code.

Comment: Bear in mind that your user(s) may not be in control of the drive names.

Comment: @CountLessQ `Console.ReadLine();` in asp.net? You are way off track.